# transparent torification

Tags: configuration

I'm using the Anonabox as internet connection. As its hardware connects to Tor, it is recommended to activate 'transparent torification' in the Tor browser to avoid running everything through Tor twice (resulting in speed loss). All documentation I could find simply states clicking the onion button and selecting the box 'transparent torification'. However, I can't find that option anywhere...

Comment: it will help get an accurate answer if you tell us what OS you are using ie Windows or OSX

Comment: That graphical interface has been removed.

Comment: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/anonabox-tor-tor-skip-launch

Answer (score 0):

IIRC this was an old Vidalia feature. The new way of doing this is to use the `TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1` as a command line argument for starting the Tor Browser. You can read more about the change here:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/6009#comment:14

Comment: `TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1` alone doesn't do. It only prevents tor-launcher from starting, i.e. prevents Tor from starting. It however does not change proxy settings. You also need to either change proxy settings somehow or use a local redirection (rinetd or similar) to redirect from 127.0.0.1:9150 to the gateway (here: anonabox). And somehow keeping care of ControlPort connections also. Not simple. Whonix has the complete setup, but explaining how to use it elsewhere is quite some work.