# Anonabox & Tor (TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH)

Tags: configuration

I'm using the Anonabox and, as its hardware connects to Tor, I'm looking for something similar to the 'transparent torification' option in the Tor browser (to avoid running everything through Tor twice).
I've been told that "the new way of doing this is to use the TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1 as a command line argument for starting the Tor Browser".
However, I am quite new to all this and slightly overwhelmed by the technical aspects of documentation I could find.
Where does one enter this command? Is there any documentation available that can serve as a step-by-step guide?

Comment: Interesting. Just to make sure I understand you correctly, you want to use the tor browser with the anonabox, but not have the tor browser bundle running tor? And this is to prevent running two tor circuits over one another correct? Could you elaborate on why you do not want to run your traffic over tor twice? Thank you!

Comment: Also if you could post what OS you are using ie Windows or OSX it will help us give you a more specific answer, especially if it involves using the terminal or command line. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I read somewhere that even with the anonabox it is more secure to use the tor browser bundle than most other browsers. I also read somewhere that this 'double torification' means slowing your internet communications down and that this could be avoided by bypassing the browser's torification. this would be faster, yet still more secure than just running any other browser.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm running OS X 10.10.4.

Answer (score 1):

Tor over Tor results in "undefined behavior," it sounds like a good idea, but may break in unexpected ways, like wearing 2 condoms. You should launch your Tor Browser with `TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1` and ideally either change the network proxy settings to an open socks ports on your hardware Tor router (i.e. change the socks address from `127.0.0.1:9051` to `192.168.0.1:9050`, for example) or better yet just use an iptables NAT redirect rule on your client machine to forward connections to `127.0.0.1:9051` to your Tor router's socks port, so you don't have to mess with any settings/redo them after every update.

This assumes your Tor router is configured to provide a SOCKSport and not just a TRANSport. If it doesn't, or you can't figure out how to connect to it, using `TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1` and setting the transparent proxy option in Tor Button in the browser will work, but you just won't get the full stream isolation you would if you used a socksport and would be more vulnerable to correlation attacks as everything in the TRANSport gets pushed through the same circuit.